# Basic Authentication with Metamask

Tags: metamask, dapps, authentication

We are evaluating the option to include an Nginx script with authentication in front of a blockchain node.
One option is to use Basic Authentication in the path of the network URL in Metamask. Is anyone doing that?
The obvious disadvantage is to ask the user to configure his/her password in plain text in Metamask. Any other ideas to have a corporative authentication before submitting a transaction?
I know the concept of Metatransaction and actually we intend to use this in the future. But we are trying a simple solution first.